# Single Page Web App & appropriate oauth authorization flow

Tags: oauth, single-page-application

I'm developing a singe page page app and from researching online it looks like the implicit oauth flow is most applicable. The concern i have is that I can't use refresh tokens and I do not want to have to request the user to login frequently.

I guess one solution is long lived access tokens ?

Answer (score 1):

The Best Practice is to use the Authorization Code without client_secret and better to use [Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients
(PKCE)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) the Authorization Code. (Which allows Refresh Tokens)

The following show several OAuth 2.0 Providers and discussions using the Authorization Code (without client_secret) for SPA:

- https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#single-page-apps
- https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/oauth2-clients/single-page-apps/
- https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg16966.html
- https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg16968.html
- https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg16967.html

Comment: This is not the official best practice. It has been discussed in various places online, including the references you've linked to, but there is no guidance that came from the OAuth WG that suggests the use of Authorization Code without client_secret over implicit flow for SPAs. Unfortunately as far as SPAs are concerned there is still an ongoing debate on how to best support these clients.

Comment: For anyone looking to implement PKCE within a SPA context, you might find this library I've been working on to be helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/appauthhelper